# bluetooth does not work after resuming computer from suspend; modprobing bluetooth modules does not help

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, suspend

I am running latest Arch Linux and GNOME desktop.

I sometimes put my computer to sleep, but after resuming I find that my bluetooth does not work. I can't turn it on from gnome system settings.
I tried running `sudo modprobe btusb bluetooth` couple of times and also tried restarting bluetooth service `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service` and failed. I don't get any error on running those commands.

Comment: At least, systemd tells you *some* reason why the service could not be started, e.g. the exit code. This should also be in the journal - the relevant except would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinNyolt systemd wouldn't show error, according to systemd there is nothing wrong with bluetooth service but still bluetooth won't work

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood you saying that restarting the service failed - I thought you meant the actual `systemctl restart` failed. But the essence of my previous comment is the same: without more information from you, we cannot do much. What is the output of `bluetoothctl`, for instance? Is there any error message when turning on the power with `bluetoothctl`? Does `dmesg` say anything? Please give more diagnostic.

Comment: @MartinNyolt here is the [link to some outputs](http://sprunge.us/DdJJ). systemctl, dmesg,bluetoothctl don't give any kind of error, I checked all of them when my bluetooth wasn't starting

Comment: Check `rfkill list all` as it looks like bluetooth may have been disabled

Comment: @Jeremy31 right now I have resume my laptop from suspend, I checked `rfkill list all` and show that bluetooth is not hard and soft blocked

Comment: Note: I don't face this problem on the same laptop anymore. Probably fixed at 'kernel level'

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, I have the Atheros AR9485. It seems that you have to enable bluetooth coexistence manually. In this website
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath9k/btcoex 
It says that the bluetooth card is AR3012. 
The only way I solved it was doing (I added this to a systemd sleep script)

```
modprobe -r ath9k &&
modprobe -r ath3k &&
modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1 &&
modprobe ath3k
```

Comment: I am not sure if this answer will help me (or anybody else) since the issue was fixed for my laptop in later versions of Linux kernel.